# Disconnecting from HttpURLConnection when returning an InputStream from a Webservice

Tags: java, sockets, connection, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I have a webservice that is making calls to a Swift cluster and found that the connections to it are sitting in a CLOSE_WAIT state and not being closed until the HA proxy forcefully closes the connection and logs the event, causing a large number of events to be generated.

Looking into this I have found that this was due to not disconnecting from the underlying HttpURLConnection once we have finished with our connection.

So I have gone through and made the necessary changes to a majority of our RESTful services but I am not sure how I should go about disconnecting from the HttpURLConnection in the case where we are returning an InputStream we retrieve from Swift straight from the webservice.

Is there some kind of a best practice for what should be done in this instance that I am not aware of or can anyone think of any good ideas to disconnect after the stream has been consumed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up just wrapping the InputStream in a object that stores the HttpURLConnection as well and calls the disconnect method once it has finished reading the stream

```
public class WrappedInputStream extends InputStream{

        InputStream is;
        HttpURLConnection urlconn;

        public WarppedInputStream(InputStream is, HttpURLConnection urlconn){
            this.is = is;
            this.urlconn = urlconn;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException{
            int read = this.is.read();
            if (read != -1){
                return read;
            }else{
                is.close();
                urlconn.disconnect();
                return -1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException{
            int read = this.is.read(b);
            if (read != -1){
                return read;
            }else{
                is.close();
                urlconn.disconnect();
                return -1;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException{
            int read = this.is.read(b, off, len);
            if (read != -1){
                return read;
            }else{
                is.close();
                urlconn.disconnect();
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do this. The connection pool underlying `HttpURLConnection` should close the underlying TCP connection after a smallish number of seconds, I believe 15s, of idle time. By calling `disconnect()` you are disabling the connection pool completely, which wastes more network and server resources by requiring a new connection per call.